# Does Ansibe support Python 3? If you require Python 3 support use the `dnf` Ansible module instead

Tags: python, ansible

When I configure python3 for target node for example as follows

```
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

This results in an error message on tasks that use `package` module.

> The Python 2 bindings for rpm are needed for this module. If you
> require Python 3 support use the `dnf` Ansible module instead

This make me wonder if Ansible supports Python 3 on target nodes. On my controller node I have Ansible 2.10.3 / Python 3.6.9 which seems to work fine. But on the target node the very very common `package` module is no longer usable and needs to be replace with `dnf` module.

The problem is that thousands of Ansible roles published on Ansible Galaxy use the `package` module.

The conclusion is that Ansible 2.10.3 does not support Python 3 in practice?

Wouldn't it be better to change the `package` module to support dnf? That way we wouldn't have to change all the Ansible roles for Python 3. Ansible Galaxy roles ideally would not have to be changed to support a different version of Python. If at all possible.

In any case, what is the recommend practice currently? Don't use Python 3 on target nodes?

Comment: My solution was to simply use the "command" task to run `yum` explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: `Ansible` supports python 3 on both controller and target but not all of its modules. `yum` is one of those.

---

From the [`package` module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_module.html):

> This module actually calls the pertinent package modules for each system (apt, yum, etc).

So unless you override the package manager you want to run with the [`use` parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_module.html#parameter-use), `package` will run the `yum` module for operating systems using it.

From the [`yum` module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html)

> This module only works on Python 2

So for those systems, you will need to use python 2 on the target when running the `package` module. And chances are this is the case when using [interpreter discovery](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html)

For systems (e.g. more recent rhel/centos os) using `dnf`, `package` will run the [corresponding module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/dnf_module.html) with any version of python >= 2.6